# dosing vs administration in academic writing

Tags: word-choice, academia

I'm writing a clinical trial report. I collected blood sample after i injected drug to the subjects . When i want to use a shorter term to indicate the timing, should i use **"after dosing"** or **"after administration"**?

A little thoughts of me, "dosing" sounds more likely people focus on the experimenter, while "administration" the *subject*(as in grammar) is the *subjects*(i.e. volunteers or patients). As the whole report is conducted in third person, I'm not sure which real point of view is more adequate.

Comment: *dosing* = "**administering** a dose to (a person or animal)." So use whichever sense is important in the context.

Comment: "After the drug was administered"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say "after administration" because "dosing" has other meanings, e.g.setting a dosage or dividing out a specified dose.  So "administration" focuses on the actual injection.  If you want to clarify that you injected the planned amount, you could say "after [administering] [injecting] the specified dose"